# Passing the -lm flag to qt compiler to get rid of "cannot open file “m.lib”

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qmake

I'm compiling a library in qt and during compiling it I've faced with this error(on windows 7 x64 with qt designer) :

cannot open file “m.lib”

when I searched around I've found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218426/using-cimg-lnk1181-cannot-open-file-m-lib-on-windows-7-x64) that I must pass the -lm flag to compiler, but I don't know how to pass it?!

I've left it in qmake flags but it says that it's unknown!

I'm using qt-designer with qt5.2 and msv2012 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries

You probably need to tell it where the library is, too.

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/my/lib -lm
```

Hope that helps.